# structure of the svn

Tags: svn

I have small project with 5 guys. I have some questions:

- Should I use branch tag and trunk structure?
- What is an efficient directory hierarchy for small project?

Comment: "brunch tag" – sounds delicious.

Comment: @phineas instead of using name as tag, should I use "subVersion" as a name ?

Comment: Usually tags are versions, ie `0.9`, `1.0`, `2.1-beta`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason not to use branch/tags/trunk, because worst case you have two empty directories, and best case you find it useful.

The appropriate directory structure within the trunk will generally be dictated by the technologies you use, as opposed to the source control.